# Microsoft Access query criteria: when I type ] , it does not show it

Tags: ms-access, square-bracket

I try to type **]** in Access queries but it does not show it. I thought my keyboard has a problem but when I type in Microsoft word, it works. I even tried to copy ] from somewhere and pasted it in Access criteria, but it does not paste it. Please let me know how to fix this problem. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you typing ] in criteria? Edit question to show SQL statement and where you want to type this character.

Comment: I mean for example in Access query I need to type parameter query as : [Enter student number] but Access does not display the closed bracket.

Comment: Don't know why this happens. Cannot reproduce behavior. I do not even use dynamic parameterized query and especially not popup input prompt because cannot validate user input. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html